# app has unfortunately stopped (facebook login)

Tags: android, facebook

I have no clue why it shows "app unfortunately stopped" error. I have seen the DDMS session and all it says is "Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!"

The mainactivity.java is:

package com.example.iwashere;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {


Facebook fb;

ImageView button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String facebook_app_id = getString (R.string.facebook_app_id);
        fb = new Facebook (facebook_app_id);
        button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateButtonImage();
    }

       private void updateButtonImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
            button.setImageResource(R.id.logout);
        } else{
            button.setImageResource(R.id.login);
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)

        {
             if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            //button close our session - logout of facebook
                try {
                   fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                   updateButtonImage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
             else {

            //login to facebook
             fb.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

             @Override
             public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

             @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

             @Override
             public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
         }
    }


      @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

}

and xml is:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background1"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.iwashere.MainActivity" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/login" />

          <ImageView 
             android:id="@+id/logout"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/logout" 
              android:visibility="invisible"/>


     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post logcat ?

Comment: On what action it stops ? Please clarify

Comment: If you have new android adtbundle when you create a new project the android comp v7 automatically created if you are using old version mean its not support try to update your version then it will generate automatically

Comment: jibran it doesnt start the app, it says unfortunately I was here app has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
  extends ActionBarActivity
```

replace by

```
   extends Activity
```

Remove this:

```
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```